# Haskell list construction and memory usage

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have the following piece of code:

```
a = reverse b
doSomething a
```

Will memory for the list `a` be actually allocated, or will `doSomething` simply reuse the list `b`? If the memory is going to be allocated, is there a way to avoid it? Doubling memory usage just because I need a reversed list doesn't sound particularly nice.

Comment: Hard to tell. The spine of the list will probably end up being duplicated -- this is tricky to assess, since 1) there are many optimizations which can avoid that, and 2) laziness makes it possible to consume that new list as soon as it is produced, so that the new spine actually consumes a constant amount of memory. In any case, the elements of the list are not duplicated (only the spine).

Comment: depending on your other use-cases, you're better off using [Data.Sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.9.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) instead of lists anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case, both `a` and `b` will exist in memory in their entirety. Note that even then, *the contents of* the two lists will only exist once, shared between both lists, so we're only talking about the "spine" of the lists existing twice.

In the best case, depending on how `b` is defined and what `doSomething` does, the compiler might do some hoopy magic to turn the whole thing into a tight constant-space loop that generates the contents of the list as it processes them, possibly involving no memory allocation at all. Maybe.

But even in the very worst case, you're duplicating the spine of the lists. You'll never duplicate the actual elements *in* the list.

(Each cons node is, what, 3 pointers? I think...)